# How to terminate a program on a BSP when default kill (-9/all) options do not work

Tags: linux

I have written a program for basic file reading/writing. When I added lseek, a function new to me it did not terminate. I have tried to use the following commands to get it to do so:

```
ctrl 
kill PID 
kill -9 PID 
killall Processname
```

I have disconnected the telnet session, but the host is still reachable.

Since it is a BSP for an embedded device, it does not support all commands. For instance, ps will only return:

```
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND 
1001 root       0:00 ./07-7
```

I have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694720/how-is-it-possible-that-kill-9-for-a-process-on-linux-has-no-effect but due to the previously mentioned limitation I can not see ps STAT, or execute ps axopid,comm,wchan.

Since the board is on a remote location, with no-one in place and other users in need to use it over the weekend, I do not want to reboot it. I can also not just let the program run, since it has a lock on a shared file needed by others. Any advice would be appreciated!

Code:

```
write(fd, pix1, 64);
lseek(fd, -19, SEEK_SET); //added last, after which it did not recover
read(fd, pix2, 64);
close(fd);
```

Comment: Bizarre... It won't respond to `kill -9`? How about `sudo kill -9`?

Comment: After reading the other question, I suspect the failing storage medium sleep. Can you launch another process (with a timeout) to see if the storage medium is failing?

Comment: @Linuxios I am logged in as root, the only user possible on this board.

Comment: Hm. Very, very odd. What kind of storage medium is it, and are they custom drivers, or Linux drivers. (eg. is it SATA or PATA, or is it something odd and exotic)?

Comment: I can still write to other files on the disk. I can not write to the particular file which is locked by open() in the stalling program

Comment: Hold don.There is something *very* wrong with the problem line. You're trying to set the offset to `-19`. That's not right. I think that might even be an underflow, depending on underlying type. Change that to a sensible value and give it a try.

Comment: Your are right, it is indeed possible that I went back too far. I have been programming too many hours in a row, so I just used a calculator for 64/4. Unfortunately, it was set to hex, return 19 instead of 16. So if lseek jumps with int, I indeed created an underflow. However, I can not change the value. The old program is stuck and I can not access the file anymore.

Comment: I know, but that's your problem. Just do a restart if you can. If you can't, try force unmounting the volume if you can. If not that, you can try killing through GDB.

Comment: I can not unmount the volume (OS is on it) and there is no gdb on the embedded device. I am afraid I will just have to contact the admin to see what has to be done to restart the device (or be more precise, to be sure that it will boot properly and auto-reconnect)
Thank you for your responses! Is there a way to give you some credit for your effort?

Comment: I can make them an answer if you want.

Comment: @Linuxios please do make in to an answer, this [has been discussed](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931) over in SF.meta.

Comment: @Linuxios please do make in to an answer, see [the discussion](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931) in SF.meta. – terdon 3 hours ago

Comment: @terdon tomorrow, when I have time.

Comment: A two-step suggestion: step (1) Create a random scratch file and run your program on it.  If that process cannot be killed, either, then the problem may lie in the `lseek`; continue with step (2).  If that process can be killed normally, then the problem lies elsewhere — perhaps there’s just something wrong with the file.  Continue investigating.

Comment: Step (2) Change your program from `lseek(…, –19, …)` to either `lseek(…, 19, …)` or `lseek(…, 16, …)`.  Create another random scratch file and run your modified program on that.  If that process can be killed normally, then the problem almost surely lies with the `lseek`, and there’s probably nothing to do but reboot.  However, if that process cannot be killed, then the mystery grows deeper.